# How to create rounded shape of chile row on expandable list view in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, rounded-corners

I have created expandable list view.I want to create rounded child row.I have created the last child row as rounded shape.But when we expand and collapse of expandable list view then rounded child row has been change position.How to handle this problem.please suggest me.

Comment: It would be better to understand your issue if you can post some code & screenshot of your issue.

Answer (score 2):

first define a drawable for round rectangle background,

**round_rect_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF6363ff" />

<solid android:color="#10FFFF64" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Then you can set this drawable as a background of your child row,

**child_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/round_rect_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPlayerName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```